# too much memory used by glide in loading images?

Tags: android, android-glide

Hi i am currently testing an app i created, with is sorta like instagram. Am using glide as the image loader, but i quickly ramped upwards of 100 plus ram usage in about 4-5 images, am using save DiskCacheStrategy.ALL in a 400 x 400 imageview, how do i avoid the excessive ram usage and how do the big apps- instagram,facebook go about memory management.

```
 Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(Uri.fromFile(file))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_media)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder_error_media)
            .dontAnimate()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.All)
            .skipMemoryCache( true )
            .override(400, 400)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(mMediaThumb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the tutorial in the following link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-optimizing-by-loading-images-in-custom-sizes to request image in a certain dimensions so there won't be a big payload